# Form Submit not getting input values on Spring framework with editable js

Tags: java, jquery, spring

My Code:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="user">
    <a href="#" id="edit_postcode" data-title="Post code:">
              <span style="font-weight: bold"></span>${user.postcode} </a>
    <input type="submit" class="btnhov" value="save" />
</form:form>
```

I need to submit the values from `edit_postcode` anchor tag.While clicking submit button values from  `edit_postcode`  getting submitting. But when we use `<form:input path="postcode">` with path attribute, I am getting values on submit. Can any one guide me for the same.

The project is in `j2ee` and the front end code is using `jsp`.  I am also using `editable.js` for the purpose of editing.

Comment: Why you want to submit form when you are using editable.js?

Comment: your path attribute should match with property on the commandBean. Then only spring mvc will be able to assign the value to the backing bean